# SQL Server: ColumnName specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument

Tags: sql-server

I try to dynamically pivot my table `#TempAttributes`.

For every different `ATTRIBUTEID` I want it to name a column correspondingly and add the `VALUE` per `REFRECID` per row.

Edit: removed the Sample data, because this now does work. The problem lies within the column names.

The code I use (Edit: built it from scratch again, simplified, same error):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TBL_TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##TBL_TEMP

DECLARE @SQLQUERY AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @Columns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Columns = COALESCE(@Columns + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(ATTRIBUTEID)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ATTRIBUTEID FROM AARSATAttributeRefBIStaging WHERE ATTRIBUTEID <> '') AS B
ORDER BY B.ATTRIBUTEID
SELECT @Columns

SET @SQLQUERY = N'SELECT [REFRECID],' + @Columns + '
INTO ##TBL_TEMP
FROM [dbo].[AARSATAttributeRefBIStaging]
PIVOT (MAX([Value])
    FOR [AttributeID] IN (' + @Columns + ')) AS Q'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQUERY
```

The error I receive:

"The column name "AttributeId" specified in the PIVOT operator conflicts with the existing column name in the PIVOT argument."

When I SELECT the columns, I get many columns (I know):

```
[Aandeel in VvE], [Aangebroken complex], [Aanklgroen], [Aannemer], [Aanrecht], [Aantal kamers], [Aantal plekken contract], [Aantal punten buitenruimte], [Aantal punten energieprestatie], [Aantal punten gemeenschappelijke voorzieningen], [Aantal punten keuken], [Aantal punten overige ruimtes], [Aantal punten sanitair], [Aantal punten vertrekken], [Aantal punten verwarming], [Aantal punten woonvoorziening gehandicapten], [Aantal punten WOZ], [Aantal punten WOZ deel 1], [Aantal punten WOZ deel 2], [Aantal punten WOZ totaal], [Aantal punten WWS totaal], [Aantal punten WWS totaal TMS], [Aantal punten zorgwoning], [Aantal_liften], [Aanwezigheid huismeester in het gebouw], [Aanwezigheid zorgverlener in het gebouw], [ABC_lijst], [Achterstallig onderhoud], [Achterstallig onderhoud per m??], [Achterstallig onderhoud per m²], [Acquisitiekader], [Architect], [AttributeId], [Bad], [Bad+douche], [Badkamer], [Basisschoo], [Bedrijven], [Beheercode VGM], [Beklemming], [Beleidslabel], [Beoordeling contact met buurtbewoners], [Beoordeling contact met medebewoners], [Beoordeling levendigheid in het gebouw], [Bereikb], [Berging], [Beschermd stads-/dorpsgezicht], [beschrijving_gebouw], [Bestemming], [Bestemming_IPD], [Bestemmingsplan], [Bewonercie], [Bijkeuken], [Brandveiligheid], [Buitenruim], [BVO], [BVOGEM], [Carport], [CO2-uitstoot], [Conditiemeting NEN 2767], [Constructeur], [CV-installateur], [DAEB], [Douche], [Douche rmt], [dPi Typering], [Duur_afkoop_erfpacht], [Egw], [Einddatum huur], [E-installateur], [Energie-index], [Energie-index datum afmelding certificaat], [Energie-lb], [EPA view], [Erfpacht], [Erfpacht uitponden verkoop], [Experiment], [Exploitatiebeperking 7 jaar], [Ext keuken], [Ext santai], [Feitelijk_gebruik], [Financieringsregime], [Garage], [GBO], [GBOGEM], [Gebouw categorie bij mutatie], [Gebouw type bij mutatie], [Gebrgroen], [Gekozen scenario], [Geliberaliseerd], [GemSchappBuitenruimte], [Gereguleerd (marktwaarde)], [Huurcontract_zorghuis], [Huurgroep], [Huurkorting in maanden], [Huurverhogingsgroep], [In huursombenadering], [Incentives 2018], [Incentives 2019], [Incentives 2020], [Incentives 2021], [Incentives 2022], [Incentives 2023], [Incentives 2024], [Ingangsdatum huur], [Jaar eerste actie], [Jaar klanttevredenheid], [Jaar meting NEN 2767], [Jaar_afkoop_erfpacht], [Jaar_afloop_erfpacht], [Juridische_status_grond], [Kadastraal_gesplitst], [Kadastrale_bepalingen], [Kelder], [Keuken], [Koopoptie], [Krediet_2011], [Krediet_2012], [Krediet_2013], [Krediet_2014], [Krediet_2015], [Krediet_2016], [Krediet_2017], [Krediet_2018], [Krediet_2019], [Leegstand in maanden], [Leegstand per 1 januari], [Leegstand per 1 oktober], [Loodgieter], [Looptijd bij herziening in jaren], [Maatschappelijk perspectief], [Markthuur per jaar], [Markthuur per m?? VVO], [Markthuur per m² VVO], [Mate waarin aan activiteiten wordt deelgenomen], [Mate waarin activiteiten worden georganiseerd], [Mate waarin bewoners de zorgorganisatie zouden aanbevelen], [Mate waarin bewoners helpen iets te organiseren], [Mate waarin bewoners vrijwilligerswerk doen], [Mate waarin de zorgpartner Habion zou aanbevelen], [Mate waarin gebouw over 5 jaar aansluit bij zorgorganisatie], [Mate waarin het gebouw aansluit bij de zorgorganisatie], [Mate waarin men het wonen in het gebouw zou aanbevelen], [Mate waarin men plezierig woont], [Max16won], [Maximaal aantal verkopen], [Methode], [Milieuaspecten], [Mutatiegraad 2014], [Mutatiegraad 2015], [Mutatiegraad 2016], [Mutatiegraad 2017], [Mutatiegraad 2018], [Mutatiekans BOG | MOG | ZOG], [Mutatiekans complex], [Mutatiekosten marketing], [Mutatiekosten technisch], [Object_IPD], [Omvang_renovatie], [Onderhoudsconditiemeting], [Opbvervoer], [Oppervlakte overige ruimten], [Oude_objectnaam], [Overig 1], [Overig 2], [Overig VW], [Parkeerpl], [Perc_kostprijs_bij_gemengde_huur], [Perc_toedeling_slapend_complex], [Percentage wtzi], [Pljkind], [Plokind], [Pntomg], [Pref_Scen_HS], [Prijs-kwaliteitverhouding van de woning], [Projectleider bouw], [Projectleider_bouw], [Punten Bad/Douche], [PvE_Vastgoed], [Realisatielabel], [Scenario], [Schuur], [Service], [Slaapkmr 1], [Slaapkmr 2], [Slaapkmr 3], [Slaapkmr 4], [Slaapkmr 5], [Slaapkmr 6], [Sloop], [Soort_dak], [Status], [Stedelijke], [Stimulering hergebruik materialen], [Strategielabel], [Taxatie], [Technisch adviseur], [Tevredenheid bewoners over het gebouw], [Tevredenheid over de huismeester], [Tevredenheid over de kwaliteit van de woning], [Tevredenheid over de kwaliteit van het gebouw], [Tevredenheid over de kwaliteit van leven], [Tevredenheid over de veiligheid in het gebouw], [Tevredenheid over de verpleging], [Tevredenheid over de voorzieningen in de buurt], [Tevredenheid over de zorg die wordt geleverd], [Tevredenheid over georganiseerde activiteiten], [Tevredenheid over het leefklimaat in de woning], [Tevredenheid partners over samenwerking met Habion], [Toelating_behandeling], [Toelichting huurverhoging], [Toeslag zorgwoning], [Toilet], [Transformatie], [Type], [type ABC-lijst], [Typering monitor maatschappelijke bijdrage], [Vastetrap], [Vastgoedmanager], [Verhogingsmoment], [Verkeer], [Verkoop], [Verkoop/sloopjaar], [Vertrek ST], [Vertrek VW], [Vestigingskader], [VHE ID Marktwaarde], [VHE ID marktwaarde nieuw], [VHE_VGM], [VHESubType], [Vhe-type], [Videofoon], [Voorzien], [Vrijstelling verhuurdersheffing], [VVE], [VVO], [Waardebe?»nvloedende omstandigheden], [Waardebeïnvloedende omstandigheden], [Waarderingsmodel TMS (Gebruik)], [Wasruimte], [Wastafel], [Werkmaatschappij], [Winkels], [Wonen], [Woningverbeterende werkzaamheden gepland], [Woonkamer], [Woonkamer2], [Woonomgevi], [Woonquote], [Woonvorm], [WWSGEM], [Zelfstandig], [Zolder], [Zolder rmt], [ZR_2012], [ZR_2013], [ZR_2014], [ZR_2015], [ZR_2016], [ZR_2017], [ZR_2018], [ZR_2019], [Zware_zorg]
```

What do I miss here? I've successfully used a similar query for other tables.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? You should be getting "Invalid column name" errors since REFRECID and ATTRIBUTEID in your second query don't match RECRECID and ATTRIBUTE in your first query.

Comment: sql server 2012. I saw indeed in the sample dataset I had to chance the column names. I fixed that, and I concluded that my dataset actually does work on the dynamic query. So the problem lies in the actual dataset. I posted the columns output above, in which the error lies.

Comment: It doesn't like that `AttributeId` is on the left of `IN` as well as inside the `IN` list. This self contained example - `select * from (values (1,'a')) t(v,a) pivot (MAX(v) for a in ([a])) u` - generates the same error.

Comment: I don't  understand the error. I rewrote my Dynamic SQL code entirely as simple as possible. I want per REFRECID the VALUE in ATTRIBUTEID columns, a simple pivot. ATTRIBUTEID is standing exactly where it should be if I would like to pivot it. How to work around this issue?